# Can I upload a Book to Arxiv which I have already Published?

Tags: publications, online-publication

A few years ago I published a book on mathematics and physics.  This book received positive feedback from people who read it, but was never widely read and has not sold that many copies.  At this point, I would prefer if the book were just made freely available as it is probably never going to make a huge amount of money anyway, so I was wondering if I could make some alterations to the manuscript and then upload it to Arxiv with a summary of the content and the intended reader?

Would this be copyright infringement as I suppose I have already signed a contract with the publisher?  I don't remember the details of the contract, but I suppose the publisher would not want me to do this, as it means people who might happen to want to read it will do a Google search and see that there is a free PDF copy, whereas the publisher would want to make money from the book wherever possible.  Is there something about Arxiv which sidesteps this copyright issue, as I am uploading a slightly different document to Arxiv which will exist independently of the physical book.

Comment: You might need to check what you have signed but it is probable that you still own the prepublication version and can make it available. The ovious example would be Peter Webb's book. http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/RepBook/index.html

Comment: This is possible but not sure if guaranteed.  Are you saying just upload the PDF which I have with the alterations I was planning and then call it the prepublication version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your publisher cares, then it would be dangerous to do this. They might be willing to give permission if they no longer get revenue from the book. They might even respond positively to a request to give the rights back to you.

"Slightly different" is an interpretation. I doubt that your interpretation and that of a publisher/rights_holder would be the same.

But ask. Don't assume anything.

Answer (score 8):

It's very dangerous to say "I suppose I have already signed a contract". This is legal stuff. The exact wording is important! If you have signed a contract, *take it out and read it*. What exactly did you agree to?

The odds are good you'll have to ask the publisher about whether you can do this. Even if the contract said you can't do this, it's possible they'll still say yes, especially if they've stopped actively trying to sell the book. Nonetheless, they might impose other restrictions - for example they might say you can only post the raw manuscript (i.e. no redrawn figures, no title & half-title pages if they were prepared by the publisher, no book cover [again if it was prepared by the publisher], no special fonts ...).

In any case asking the publisher is never going to be wrong, so I recommend doing that.

Comment: probably no index as well. Also, you really want to have the verbal permission written. Talk to them via mail, electronic or otherwise.